# Run Facebook SDK sample apps in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

Novice question.

What is the recommended way to run the sample apps, included in the Facebook SDK, in Android Studio (0.8.6)?

The ideal answer would include step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Android Studio version 0.8.0, and Facebook SDK 3.18.

When I tried to open a sample as a separate project, it can't find Gradle and wasn't able to run it. However, when I imported /samples folder as a root, all sample projects were imported and was able to run each samples.

```
File > Import Project > Select FACEBOOK_SDK_PATH/samples > OK > Create project from existing sources
```

and then, click next/ok as Android Studio's default setting.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Suposing you already downloaded and unzipped the SDK.

1. Create your android project. Gradle based.
2. File -> Import Module. Navigate to the unzipped folder and select the unzipped folder.
3. Add the library dependency in your main module (the one created with your project) adding this line in your build.gradle:
4. Synchonize project.

If you want to continue creating your own app, you might add the dependency module `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    dependencies {
        compile project (':facebook')
    }
}
```